# Почему после окончания действия условия @media-запроса, стиль не возвращается к исходному виду?

Tags: css, адаптивная-верстка, media-queries

Вот сам проект: https://codepen.io/Coder10000000000/pen/NWjjqyb

Есть адаптивное меню, пункты выводятся горизонтально ("display:flex")

При ширине экрана меньше 1024, меню отображается вертикально, становится "display: block"

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .btn--menu {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  #show-menu:checked ~ .navigation .menu-list{
    display: block;
  }

  .menu-list {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 53px;

    & .menu-sublist {
      position: initial;
      padding-left: 10px;
    }
  }
}
```

Так же, в правом верхнем углу появляется иконка, которая скрывает/раскрывает пункты меню

Казалось бы, всё работает. Но проблема в том, что если на узком экране (в режиме "display:block"), открыть меню, а после этого, не закрывая его, расширить экран больше 1024px, то меню так и остаётся в режиме display:block

**То есть, при возврате экрана в широкое состояние, стиль после @media запроса не возвращается к исходному виду**

Я решил проблему с помощью такой записи:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1025px) {
  .menu-list{
    display: flex !important;
  }
}
```

Но этот подход мне кажется очень топорным

*1) Почему после возврата к широкому экрану, стиль не возвращается к исходному виду? Нормально ли это?*

*2) Какие есть адекватные способы решения проблемы? (дополнительный медиа-запрос и !important выглядят очень плохим подходом)*

Comment: У вас в 13-й строке ошибка, должен быть `display: flex` а не `block` : `#show-menu:checked ~ .navigation .menu-list{display: flex;}` и не нужно писать условие при `min-width: 1025px` так как в 13-й строке вы задаете по умолчанию. т.е. по умолчанию вы задаете `block` и потом переназначаете при `1024` опять `block`, вы опечатались

Comment: Оформил в виде ответа, проверте

Comment: Большое спасибо, действительно.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему такая запись работает:
#show-menu:checked ~ .navigation .menu-list{
  display: flex; 
 }

А если просто указать нужный класс для манипуляций, то не работает?
#show-menu:checked .menu-list{
  display: flex; 
 }

Все примеры в интернете, что я нашел, используют селекторы ~ либо +

Comment: [Селектор](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) `~` говорит что найти соседний элемент с `#show-menu:checked` с классом `.navigation`. В свою очереь запись ` #show-menu:checked .menu-list` нам говорит искать  `.menu-list` вложенный в `#show-menu:checked`

Comment: Так же вы можете отметить ответ как верный.

Comment: Получается, что это работает не так, как у псевдокласса :hover, после которого можно указать любой класс на странице. Спасибо за разъяснение

Comment: работает так же как :hover. Добавил объяснение в ответ после UPD. ~ селектор который говорит искать по **соседству** а не как **дочерний** элемент, а просто через пробел запись говорит искать один объект вложенный в другой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас по ссылке в codepen опечатка в 13-й строке, должно быть:

```
#show-menu:checked ~ .navigation .menu-list{
  display: flex; 
 }
```

У Вас

```
#show-menu:checked ~ .navigation .menu-list{
   display: block; 
}
```

Логика - в 13-й строке вы задаете вид меню по умолчанию - `display: flex`, в частном случае, при `< 1024px` задаете как `display: block`

```css
body{
  background-color: #000;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
}


#show-menu {
  display: none;
}

#show-menu:checked ~ .navigation .menu-list{
  display: flex; /* ОПЕЧАТКА должен быть flex у вас block*/
}

.btn--menu{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  background-color: #fff;
  & img {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
  }
}

.navigation {
  z-index: 1;
  & a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 1.3;

    &:hover {
      background-color: #131d4a;
      border-radius: 2px;
    }
  }
}

.menu-list {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;

  & li:hover > .menu-sublist{
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    max-height: initial;
  }

  & li:hover > .ico-caret:after {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
}

.menu-sublist {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;

  & .menu-sublist {
    position: initial;
    padding-left: 10px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .btn--menu {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  #show-menu:checked ~ .navigation .menu-list{
    display: block;
  }

  .menu-list {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 53px;

    & .menu-sublist {
      position: initial;
      padding-left: 10px;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="show-menu">
<label for="show-menu" class="btn--menu"><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/wirecons-free-vector-icons/32/menu-alt-512.png" alt=""></label>
<nav class="navigation">
    <ul class="menu-list">
        <li><a href="#">Меню1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Меню1</a>
            <ul class="menu-sublist">
                <li><a href="#">Меню2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Меню2</span></a>
                    <ul class="menu-sublist">
                        <li><a href="#">Меню3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Меню3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Меню3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Меню2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Меню1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Меню1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Меню1</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

UPD:

> Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему такая запись работает: #show-menu:checked ~ .navigation .menu-list{ display: flex; } А если просто указать нужный класс для манипуляций, то не работает? #show-menu:checked .menu-list{ display: flex; }

Дело все в селекторе ([точнее комбинаторе](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator)) **`~`**

Строка `#show-menu:checked ~ .navigation .menu-list` нам говорит найти все **соседние** элементы с классом `.navigation` к элементу с id `show-menu` и в состояни `:cheked` и далее во всех найденых элементах найти элементы с классом `menu-list`. Визульно это выглядит так:

```css
div{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
#show-menu:checked ~ .navigation{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div><!-- какой то родитель или body -->
  <div class="navigation"></div> <!-- этот элемент не подходит под условие так как стоит до элемента с id show-menu-->
  <input id="show-menu" type="checkbox" checked>
  <div class="navigation"> <!-- Соседний элемент с классом navigation-->
  </div>
  <div class="someclass"></div>
 <div class="navigation"> <!-- Соседний элемент с классом navigation-->
  </div>
</div>
```

А запись `#show-menu:checked .menu-list` означает что элемент `.menu-list` находится внутри элемента `#show-menu`. Визуально:

```
<!-- Визуализация вот такой #someid .navigation записи-->

<div id="someid">
  <div class="navigation"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам мешает эта часть кода

```
#show-menu:checked ~ .navigation .menu-list{
  display: block;
}
```

Эта часть Вашего кода переопределяет свойство `display: flex` потому что элемент `#show-menu` остается в состоянии `checked` если вы раскроете меню на видимой области менее 1024px и увеличите видимую область.

Если вам нужно, чтобы `#show-menu` переходило в исходное состояние, то у Вас есть два варианта:

1. Не использовать состояние `checked`, а добавлять класс `checked` (при появлении которого применяются нужные Вам стили) к `show-menu` с помощью JavaScript, например, так:

   `document.querySelector("#show-menu").classList.toggle("checked");`
2. Убирать состояние `checked` элемента `#show-menu` (ставить значение `false`) при размере окна более 1024px кода JavaScript.

   `document.querySelector("#show-menu").checked = false;`

Поищите информацию здесь - [Размеры окна](https://learn.javascript.ru/size-and-scroll-window)

Comment: Большое спасибо